Django constraint on derived fields
I am trying to add a non-overlaping constraint on a Postgres specific field DateRange field:
from django.contrib.postgres.constraints import ExclusionConstraint
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import DateRangeField, RangeOperators

class MyModel(models.Model):
    timespan = DateRangeField(blank=False, null=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=status_choices, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            ExclusionConstraint(
                name='exclude_overlapping_offer', 
                expressions=[
                    ('timespan', RangeOperators.OVERLAPS),
                    (models.Q(status='ACCEPTED'), RangeOperators.EQUAL),
                ],
            )

Basically I want to prevent having overlapping entries in the database that have status ACCEPTED.
The migration runs fine, but then when I try to save the model, I get an error:
AttributeError: 'Q' object has no attribute 'replace_expressions'

There is a reply on a bug report that says that Q objects are not allowed in the expressions of the constraint:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/34805
Is there some other way to have the constraint on a derived field?
I am using Django 5.1.


What version of Django? Add as text update to question text. 2) The bug report is for a UNIQUE constraint. 3) The most recent docs for Postgres constraints specifically show a Q object as being valid: A Q object that specifies the condition to restrict a constraint to a subset of rows. For example, condition=Q(cancelled=False). Though as shown it is using the condition keyword. Pretty sure the issue is with the combination of (models.Q(status='ACCEPTED'), RangeOperators.EQUAL.


Please include import statements for the non-standard imports, ie. DateRangeField, ExclusionConstraint, and RangeOperator

@AdrianKlaver good point about the condition, I missed that in the docs. Once I added it, I get stuck with a different error on a save from the admin:
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'status' into field. Choices are: _check

@AdrianKlaver, I managed to get it working with the condition. The FieldError from the previous comment, was because the status field was not present on the admin form.
Also the condition works, and throws an IntegrityError when trying to add overlapping records, but for some reason the django admin does throw validation erros, but instead I get a 500 error with an IntegrityError in the traceback. I have other similar models with no-overlap constraints, that work well with the django admin.
Anyway tou can add the answer so I can accept it

The answer lies here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/contrib/postgres/constraints/

condition


ExclusionConstraint.condition
A Q object that specifies the condition to restrict a constraint to a subset of rows. For example, condition=Q(cancelled=False).
These conditions have the same database restrictions as django.db.models.Index.condition

Use condition to supply the non-range value you want to filter the rows you want to apply the range restrictions to.
